# Mostrar Errores a través de controlador

Tags: laravel, mensajes

Estoy trabajando con Laravel 5 y me pregunto si es posible crear un controlador y dentro de este, funciones que envíen alertas o errores controlados, para en la vista obtener la función del error o mensaje que solicito según sea el caso.

Ejemplo: cuando intento ver una lista de registros, si esta vacía, necesito un mensaje que diga el mensaje "No hay registros que mostrar", de lo contrario listar los registros.

Actualmente lo hago a través de un DIV dentro del else, así:

> **Ooops!** No hay registros que mostrar.

Pero pensaba en algo más estandar para sólo hacer referencia.

Comment: hola @AtyFlow, tu pregunta carece de la información necesaria para que la comunidad la considere como apta para el sitio. deberías de darte una vuelta por el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para ver como son las preguntas en SOes, saludos!

Comment: No entiendo realmente el título de tu pregunta. ¿deseas mostrar errores en el controlador sin pasar a la vista? O te refieres a crear una especie de servicio que pueda administrar y generar alertas según los parámetros que le entregues?

Comment: pensaba metodos en el controlador, y dependiendo lo que necesite, hacer la referencia a ese metodo desde la vista. ó tendria que hacer una vista con el error, para luego hacer  referenci a la vista, dependiendo del error? @Shaz

Comment: ¿Pasar de la vista al controlador para una alerta? No me parece una buena idea, en teoría deberías hacer un llamado a un controlador para ejecutar alguna acción y basado en el resultado mostrar alguna alerta o notificación.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes crear un controlador segundario(por llamarlo así) con varios metodos y respuestas dependiendo del error. me explico, un metodo diferente si un array est vacio, como un emtodo diferente si no responde el servidor, luego de tener listo solo debes instanciar el controlador con un

```
Use 'ruta de controlador segundario'
```

te deberia funcionar, aunque deberas replantiar mejor tu pregunta. Suerte

Comment: Tambíen puedes crear una vista segundaria con un diseño especial para tus errores...